# What does this line of JQuery code mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I came across this post on this site with a jFiddle showing a following menu for JQUery, well I saw this piece of syntax I can't figure out.

JFiddle: http://jsbin.com/oxajeq/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Line of code I do NOT understand

```
$('#mini-logo')[logoSH](300);
```

I know the first part selects the element with id of mini-logo, but I have no idea what the rest of the syntax is! in the code, [logoSH] can become show or hide, while the () at the end means the duration. However, I can't find any example of anything using this syntax. I also googled for CSS3, JQUery, transitions, effects, animations, anything of what this might be and no luck. I find stuff that are methods, and others that are not methods but take parameters, but nothing like this code. I know that what ever is inside [] is not a method, but I can't figure out what they are. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Note that this isn't anything special about jQuery, it is just standard JavaScript object property access. It's not related to CSS.

Comment: I am still trying to understand the way JS works, so with what you said in mind, is that a js object with properties, or is it a js/jquery function?

Comment: `$('#mini-logo')` calls the `$` function,  which returns an object. The returned object has properties and methods that you can use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This construct is based on the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access properties. It allows here a dynamic selection of the method to apply ([`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)).

`logoSH` is either `"show"` or `"hide"`.

Which means your line is either

`$('#mini-logo')["show"](300);` or `$('#mini-logo')["hide"](300);`

which you can also read as

`$('#mini-logo').show(300);` or `$('#mini-logo').hide(300);`

This is a common construct, that you may also find with a ternary operator:

```
$('#mini-logo')[someBool ? "show" : "hide"](300);
```

Note: were there not the duration, you could have use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function which takes a boolean as argument.

Comment: Ok that make sense, so I am gonna guess the .show() and .hide() are JQuery functions?

Comment: @TannerSummers yes. Added links in the answer.

Comment: It seems like I need to go back and review objects, properties, and functions in JS. I am so used to java and c++, this seems to confuse me, If I remember right, JS objects can contain properties with values, or functions and from the website I was reading up on JS, it mentioned accessing a function of an object via object.function or object['function']. but I never seen it in the format of (JS) item[function](parameters) or (JQuery) $('item')[function](parameters). I really appreciate the help Denys thank you :)